The theme change button is moving
I have a theme change button on my website. But when you click on it, it moves from a fixed position to the middle of the site. How can I fix this?
css
body.dark-theme {
filter: brightness(0.6);
}
.toggleWrapper {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 0 200px;
     transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
 .toggleWrapper input {
     position: absolute;
     left: -99em;
}
 .toggle {
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     width: 90px;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: #83d8ff;
     border-radius: 84px;
     transition: background-color 200ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
 .toggle:before {
     content: 'AM';
     position: absolute;
     left: -50px;
     top: 15px;
     font-size: 18px;
}
 .toggle:after {
     content: 'PM';
     position: absolute;
     right: -48px;
     top: 15px;
     font-size: 18px;
     color: #749ed7;
}
 .toggle__handler {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     top: 3px;
     left: 3px;
     width: 44px;
     height: 44px;
     background-color: #ffcf96;
     border-radius: 50px;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
     transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
 .toggle__handler .crater {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #e8cda5;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
     border-radius: 100%;
}
 .toggle__handler .crater--1 {
     top: 18px;
     left: 10px;
     width: 4px;
     height: 4px;
}
 .toggle__handler .crater--2 {
     top: 28px;
     left: 22px;
     width: 6px;
     height: 6px;
}
 .toggle__handler .crater--3 {
     top: 10px;
     left: 25px;
     width: 8px;
     height: 8px;
}
 .star {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #fff;
     transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
     border-radius: 50%;
}
 .star--1 {
     top: 10px;
     left: 35px;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 30px;
     height: 3px;
}
 .star--2 {
     top: 18px;
     left: 28px;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 30px;
     height: 3px;
}
 .star--3 {
     top: 27px;
     left: 40px;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 30px;
     height: 3px;
}
 .star--4, .star--5, .star--6 {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: all 300ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
 .star--4 {
     top: 16px;
     left: 11px;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 2px;
     height: 2px;
     transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}
 .star--5 {
     top: 32px;
     left: 17px;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 3px;
     height: 3px;
     transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}
 .star--6 {
     top: 36px;
     left: 28px;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 2px;
     height: 2px;
     transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}
 input:checked + .toggle {
     background-color: #749dd6;
}
 input:checked + .toggle:before {
     color: #749ed7;
}
 input:checked + .toggle:after {
     color: #fff;
}
 input:checked + .toggle .toggle__handler {
     background-color: #ffe5b5;
     transform: translate3d(40px, 0, 0) rotate(0);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .toggle__handler .crater {
     opacity: 1;
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--1 {
     width: 2px;
     height: 2px;
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--2 {
     width: 4px;
     height: 4px;
     transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--3 {
     width: 2px;
     height: 2px;
     transform: translate3d(-7px, 0, 0);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--4, input:checked + .toggle .star--5, input:checked + .toggle .star--6 {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--4 {
     transition: all 300ms 200ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--5 {
     transition: all 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--6 {
     transition: all 300ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}

html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="toggleWrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="dn" id="dn"/>
  <label for="dn" class="toggle">
    <span class="toggle__handler">
      <span class="crater crater--1"></span>
      <span class="crater crater--2"></span>
      <span class="crater crater--3"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star star--1"></span>
    <span class="star star--2"></span>
    <span class="star star--3"></span>
    <span class="star star--4"></span>
    <span class="star star--5"></span>
    <span class="star star--6"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<header>Заголовок страницы</header>

<nav>Меню навигации</nav>

<aside>Боковая колонка SideBar</aside>

<article>
 Контент - основное содержимое страницы.
</article>

<footer>Подвал сайта</footer>
 
</body>
</html>

javascript
document.getElementById('dn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  const bodyElement = document.body;
  const currentTheme = bodyElement.className;

  if (currentTheme === 'light-theme') {
    bodyElement.classList.remove('light-theme');
    bodyElement.classList.add('dark-theme');

    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-theme');
  } else {
    bodyElement.classList.remove('dark-theme');
    bodyElement.classList.add('light-theme');

    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light-theme');
}});
let defaultTheme = 'light-theme';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const bodyElement = document.body;
    bodyElement.classList.remove('light-theme');
    bodyElement.classList.remove('dark-theme');
    bodyElement.classList.add(localStorage.getItem('theme') || defaultTheme);
});


@user25276022 I think what you can do is update position styles for button to absolute.
Here is the full style block.
.toggleWrapper {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 200px;
}

